# Provincial Education Act

Tags: canada

I'm doing a research paper on Regulation 17, and found that this regulation meant that in Ontario, French schools were "ignored by the provincial education act."

What does it mean if a school is ignored by this act? Does it mean that graduation from such a school would mean you couldn't say you've graduated, or that an education from such a school would be disregarded?

Comment: This seems more fit on History.SE, rather than Politics.SE.

Comment: It has it's own [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulation_17)

Comment: [Ontario Education Act](https://www.ontario.ca/laws/statute/90e02#BK0)

Answer (score 1):

It would mean that all the requirements of the Act would not have to be met. But the Act outlines the requirements of a school. They can only issue degrees however if either the [Legislative Assembly of Ontario](http://www.ontla.on.ca/web/home.do) or the [Minister of Training, Colleges and Universities](https://www.ontario.ca/page/published-plans-and-annual-reports-2015-16-ministry-training-colleges-and-universities) grants them the authority to do so. Whether they choose to take into account the Act is up to them it seems.

So, the school board would not have to follow [Part VI](https://www.ontario.ca/laws/statute/90e02#BK144)(Boards Duties and Powers) of the act meaning that they would ***not*** have to:

> *"deliver effective and appropriate education programs to its pupils"*

which could be a problem should they choose not to follow it.